# How to pass user information to utils.py in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to pass in user information to utils.py, but don't know how. Here is a part of the utils.py I am having trouble with:

```
class Calendar(HTMLCalendar):
    def formatmonth(self, withyear=True):
            events = Class.objects.filter(date__year=self.year, date__month=self.month).exclude(student=None)
    
            cal = f'<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">\n'
            cal += f'{self.formatmonthname(self.year, self.month, withyear=withyear)}\n'
            cal += f'{self.formatweekheader()}\n'
            for week in self.monthdays2calendar(self.year, self.month):
                cal += f'{self.formatweek(week, events)}\n'
            return cal
```

The problem is the queryset `events`. I want to do something like below for it:

```
if self.request.user.is_student:
    events = Class.objects.filter(date__year=self.year, date__month=self.month).exclude(student=None)
if self.request.user.is_teacher:
        events = Class.objects.exclude(student=None)
```

Basically, I want to change the queryset depending on what user is using the website. That is why I need to use something like `self.request.user` in the utils.py. I tried to do `def get_queryset(self)` in the views.py, but it doesn't seem to work. If it is possible, I would rather like to control the queryset in my views.py, not my utils.py. I hope you could help, and give me any questions that you have.

Here is my view as some of you requested:

```
class CalendarView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = Class
    template_name = 'leads/calendar.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Class.objects.filter(date=datetime.date(1111,11,11))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # use today's date for the calendar
        d = get_date(self.request.GET.get('month', None))
        # Instantiate our calendar class with today's year and date
        cal = Calendar(d.year, d.month)
        # Call the formatmonth method, which returns our calendar as a table
        html_cal = cal.formatmonth(withyear=True)
        context['calendar'] = mark_safe(html_cal)
        context['prev_month'] = prev_month(d)
        context['next_month'] = next_month(d)
        return context
    

def get_date(req_day):
    if req_day:
        year, month = (int(x) for x in req_day.split('-'))
        return datetime.date(year, month, day=1)
    return datetime.datetime.today()
        
...
```

As you can see, if `get_queryset` works, I don't need to do all of this stuff.

Comment: Do you able to see the user object into the request ? if yes what value you are able to see init.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't really understand what you want me to do. Can you please clarify?

Comment: print(self.request.user) in your `formatmonth` method and share the value.

Comment: I get this: `NameError: name 'request' is not defined`

Comment: print(self.request.user)

Comment: Here: `AttributeError: 'Calendar' object has no attribute 'request'`

Comment: how are you calling this method, can you share the view code.

Comment: I added it above. As you can see, if `get_queryset` works, I don't need to do all of this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the querset method like below, I believe date is datetime field in you model class.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return self.model.objects.filter(date=datetime.datetime(2020,11,11))
```

Comment: I get this error: `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`...

Comment: have edit the code above please try with it.

Comment: I actually just needed to use datetime.date in order for it to work. However, it still seems to not filter the model before it is rendered as a calendar.

Comment: `datetime.datetime(2020,11,11)`

Comment: Yeah... still doesn't work. When I print the `self.model.objects.filter(date=datetime.datetime(2020,11,11))` it prints correctly. However, the problem is that this has no effect on the calendar. It seems that the only "effective" queryset is the `events` in utils.py.

Comment: @coderDcoder Ever figure this one out?  I'm having same issue.